# Make radio button group full width BootstrapVue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-vue

I'd like my radio button group to be the full width of it's parent. I tried setting the width to 100% and this works on big screens but on mobile this causes my radio button group to be bigger than the screen.
I'd also like to ask how I'd be able to change the background color of the group.

```
       <b-form-row>
            <b-col>
                    <b-form-radio-group
                            class="w-100"
                            id="radioButtonGroup"
                            v-model="selected"
                            :options="freeSeats"
                            buttons
                            button-variant="primary"
                            size="lg"
                            name="radio-btn-outline"
                    ></b-form-radio-group>
            </b-col>
        </b-form-row>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try the Bootstrap v4 flex utility classes:

```html
<b-form-radio-group
  class="d-flex flex-wrap"
  id="radioButtonGroup"
  v-model="selected"
  :options="freeSeats"
  buttons
  button-variant="primary"
  size="lg"
  name="radio-btn-outline"
></b-form-radio-group>
```

Class `d-flex` switches the radio group to take the full width (instead of the default inline-flex). The `flex-wrap` class is optional, and is used to wrap the radio buttons to the next line if there are more buttons than can be shown on a single line.